# jump to logout page when closed & refresh event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Greeting All,

I found this line of code in [here](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/). Instead of returning a `leave_message` I want it to jump to logout page if function trigger. I try to insert this lines `window.location.pathname = "logout.php";` .But It not working. Can anyone help me here. Thank You.

```js
//window.location.pathname = "logout.php";

var validNavigation = false;

function wireUpEvents() {

    var dont_confirm_leave = 0; 
    var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?'


    function goodbye(e) {
        if (!validNavigation) {
            if (dont_confirm_leave!==1) {
                if(!e) e = window.event;
                //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                e.returnValue = leave_message;
                //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                }
                //return works for Chrome and Safari
                return window.location.pathname = "logout.php";
                // return leave_message;
            }
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;

    // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
    $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 116){
        validNavigation = true;
        }
    });

    // Attach the event click for all links in the page
    $("a").bind("click", function() {
        validNavigation = true;
    });

    // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
    $("form").bind("submit", function() {
        validNavigation = true;
    });

    // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
    $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
        validNavigation = true;
    });

}

// Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    wireUpEvents();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` instead `window.location.pathname`

Comment: still not working. when I refresh the page it alert appear _Changes you made may not be saved._ then it still in the same page.

Comment: is it triggered that line when you debug?